# How to block 127.0.0.1:8080

Tags: ip, localhost, blocking

I am trying to block http://127.0.0.1:8080/ in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc host file. so what i did is:

```
127.0.0.5 http://127.0.0.1:8080/AccessCtrl/login.jsp
```

But is not working, i can still access this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know ,hosts file is for DNS caching .

I mean one side must be an IP address and the other side must be Domain name server. So you can't do such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

The hosts file only maps domain names (e.g. www.example.com) to ip addresses.

Therefore your approach won't work for two reasons:

1. What you're trying to block is not a domain name, but a URL
2. The URL you're trying to block doesn't contain a domain name, but an IP address.

You should be able to "block" the domain "localhost" this way, but you'd still be able to access `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`, just not `http://localhost:8080/`.

What you need here is a firewall, like the [windows firewall](http://www.howtogeek.com/112564/how-to-create-advanced-firewall-rules-in-the-windows-firewall/).